# Codeigniter Active records Account Validation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following code:

MODEL:

```
function check_account($account_details){
        $query = $this->db->get_where('admin', array('username' => $account_details['username'] , 
                                                                                                'password' => $account_details['password']) )->result_array();
        if(!empty($query)){
        return 'Admin';
        }
        else{
        $query2 = $this->db->get_where('user_mst', array('username' => $account_details['username'],
                                                                                     'password' => $account_details['password']) )->result_array();
                if(!empty($query2)){
                return 'User';
                }
                else return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I only posted my model because view only consist of input fields for username and password and in the controller it only retrieves the data inputted and passed on to the function in the model. The above code snippet is the function which was called by the controller.

I only have 1 log in page, it checks first if the account inputted exists in the admin table, if not, then checks if it exists in the user table. IF the account inputted does not belong to the 2 tables, it returns false.

I checked admin table first because accounts in the admin belongs to the minority. whereas in the user will be most of the majority accounts. For example, if i have 5 admin accounts and 1000 user accounts.

Instead of checking if the account inputted is one of those 1000 it firsts checks if it belongs to the 5 in the admin table.

Hope my explanation is clear or at least understandable.

My question is, when i input say, SampleAccount as username even though in the database its all in small caps it still returns as though its the same.

SampleAccount(inputted) = sampleaccount(database) - should not return in the query.

Also, i would like to read some professional's opinion on how im checking the account, or should i just make 2 login pages for both user and admins.

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach($query as $arr => $result){
        if($account_details['username'] == $result['username']){
         echo ' equal';
        }
        else echo ' not equal';
    }
```

If inputted is UseRname and in the database it is Username then this is ideal.
But is there anyway, to add this in the query itself?

get_where(); like limit, etc.

Answer (score -1):

bro you had big mistake make 1 table but make coulmn name it `role`
check if 1 user 2 admin

```
function premission_check($role){  
switch($role){
case 1 :
    return 'user';
break;
case 2 :
    return 'admin';
break;

default :
return 'bad role'
break;
}}
```